# Break long dependencies in Makefile into several lines

Tags: makefile

`target: TargetA ../DirB/FileB.cpp ../DirC/FileC.o ../DirD/FileD.o ...`

This is a long line in a make file. Is it possible to break this into several lines?

Comment: Did you try a backslash (`\`), then a new line immediately after?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this. One simple way:

```
# example 1

target: targetA targetB
target: targetC targetD

target:
    @echo $@ is dependent on $?
```

Note that this will not work with pattern rules through (rules with `%` in the targets/dependencies). If you are using pattern rules (and even if you're not), you can consider doing something like:

```
# example 2

TARGET_DEPS := targetA targetB
TARGET_DEPS += targetC
TARGET_DEPS += targetD

target: $(TARGET_DEPS)
   @echo $@ is dependent on $?
```

While it's possible to use the backslash, I personally find this makes the makefiles harder to read as the meaning of the indentation becomes unclear.

Comment: Is there a difference between "example 1" and using a backslash to break up the prerequisites? (Like in zsepi's answer?)

Answer (score 40):

from the documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Splitting-Lines

> Makefiles use a “line-based” syntax in which the newline character is special and marks the end of a statement. GNU make has no limit on the length of a statement line, up to the amount of memory in your computer.
>
> However, it is difficult to read lines which are too long to display without wrapping or scrolling. So, you can format your makefiles for readability by adding newlines into the middle of a statement: you do this by escaping the internal newlines with a backslash (\) character.

It works for targets too, i.e.:

```
a b c d:
        touch $@

multiline_dependencies: a \
 b \
 c \
 d
        touch $@
```

and to verify, `make multiline_dependencies --dry-run` gives the following output

```
touch a
touch b
touch c
touch d
touch multiline_dependencies
```